# How to store different username-password key pair in SSH in GIT Bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, password, git

Current Machine: Git Bash on Windows.

Trying to connect to a Mac through SSH.

When I execute the below command:

```
ssh aisong@10.209.161.253 "ls"
Password: <myPassword>
```

Output (works as desired):

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Library
Movies
Music
Pictures
Public
```

Note: My username for gitbash is different from 'aisong'. Similarly, the password for my username is different from 'myPassword' used above for the username 'aisong'.

How do I store this password (myPassword) for the username 'aisong' permanently so that it doesn't prompt for a password next time I execute the above ssh command?

Comment: You should better set up public key authentication.